# Where can I find the last specification defining which IP addresses correspond to which continent in CIDR?

Tags: rfc, cidr

I'm looking for a specification (probably a `RFC`) defining the connection between continent and `IP addresses`. I didn't find it in the `RFC` describing `CIDR` that I have read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RFC1466](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1466.txt) define a correspondance between continents and IP address blocks but I'm not sure to which point it's implemented.

> It is proposed that a broad geographic allocation be used for these
>   blocks.  At present there are four major areas of address allocation: 
>   Europe, North America, Pacific Rim, and South & Central America.
>
> In particular, the top level block allocation be designated as   follows:
>
> Multi-regional          192.0.0.0 - 193.255.255.255
>
> Europe       194.0.0.0 - 195.255.255.255
>
> Others                 196.0.0.0 - 197.255.255.255
>
> North America           198.0.0.0 - 199.255.255.255
>
> Central/South America   200.0.0.0 - 201.255.255.255
>
> Pacific Rim             202.0.0.0 - 203.255.255.255
>
> Others                  204.0.0.0 - 205.255.255.255
>
> Others                  206.0.0.0 - 207.255.255.255